# Angular RxJs Guard wait for service's BehaviorSubject to have value

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

Apologies for the long text - just setting the scene.

I am using a AWS Amplify (Cognito) for authentication in my Angular app. AWS Amplify provide an AmplifyService that has an authStateChange$ observable that provides updates on the Authentication state.

After the user logs in it stores the Session in local/cookie storage and therefore when the page is reopened/refreshed etc. the session is returned from storage. e.g. authStateChange$ returns a state of "signedIn".

I also have a user session (AppSession) that includes some other domain information for the current users session.

```
//AppSession.ts
export interface Session {
    package?: PurchasedPackage;
    authState: string;
}
```

Because the session is used by multiple components, I am exposing it as a BehaviorSubject from my UserStore.

```
//UserStore.ts
@Injectable()
export class UserStore {
    private _session$: BehaviorSubject<AppSession>;

    get session(): Observable<Session> {
         return this._session$.asObservable();
    }
    ....
}
```

What I want to happen is that I want to set the authState property in the AppSession from the authStateChange observable. Something like

```
    //UserStore.ts

    constructor(private amplifyService: AmplifyService){
         /**
          * If the user logs in, then update their details.
         */
         this.amplifyService.authStateChanges$.subscribe(
              (event) => {
                   this._session = new BehaviorSubject({
                       authState: event.state
                   })
              }
         )
    }
```

In my app I have a homepage that should only be seen by users who are "signedIn". Therefore, I have an "UnauthenticatedGuard" that protects it as follows:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
return this.userStore.session.pipe(
  map((session) => {
    if(session && session.authState == "signedIn") {
      this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  })
)
```

}

Now the trouble is that, when I start my app, the UnauthenticatedGuard is executed before the this.amplifyService.authStateChanges$ observable has emitted the signedIn state, therefore, I get:

```
Cannot read property 'asObservable' of undefined
```

If, I set the BehaviorSubject to have an initial value of 'null' for example (or anything really), then the Guard will think that the user is not signed in and therefore allow access.

How can I only expose the BehaviorSubject once it's initial value has been set (i.e. once the authStateChanges$ observable has emitted it's value)?